# Dúvida imprimir mais de um item em retorno Web service JSON

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

Tenho um site em Wordpress e nele estou consumindo um Web Service, criei uma função para filtrar os campeonatos com base em algumas informações,
Se todas forem verdadeiras, ele retorna o nome do respectivo campeonato, as equipes, seus jogos e resultados, até então tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas estou tendo problemas em exibir todos os valores do campeonato, ele está chamando somente um dos jogos, mas existem mais de um **"campeonato":"18"** no retorno de resultados, mas na tela só está imprimindo um deles, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Teste Api */ get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    $api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
    $campeonatos = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
    $campeonatos_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonatos ), true );
    $retorno_campeonatos = array(); // <- mudar para array

    if($campeonatos_data){
        foreach($campeonatos_data as $row){
            if(!is_array($row)){
                //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
            }else{
                if($row['sexo'] == 'M' && $row['modalidade'] == 2 && $row['categoria'] == 4){
                    $retorno_campeonatos[] = array('valor' => '<td>'.$row['nome'].'</td>', 'id' => $row['codigo']); // <--- adiciona
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
?>

<script>

$(function(){

    var html = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_campeonatos as $valor){ ?>

        html += '<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#bloco-<?php echo $valor['id'];?>" role="tab"><?php echo $valor['valor'];?></a>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#myList').html(html);

});

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <div id="contents">
            <div class="list-group" id="myList" role="tablist">
            </div>

            <div id="tabList" class="tab-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
// pega os valores da primeira URL
$api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$campeonato = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
$campeonato = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonato ), true );

// pega os valores da segunda URL
$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$resultado = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
$resultado = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultado ), true );

$retorno_resultados = array();

foreach($campeonato as $camp){
    foreach($resultado as $result){
        if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
            $retorno_resultados[] = array(
                'mandante' => '<td>'.$result['mandante'].'</td>', 
                'visitante' => '<td>'.$result['visitante'].'</td>', 
                'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                'data' => '<td>'.$camp['data'],
                'placar1n' => '<td>'.$result['placar1n'].'</td>',
                'placar2n' => '<td>'.$result['placar2n'].'</td>',
                'placar1p' => '<td>'.$result['placar1p'].'</td>',
                'placar2p' => '<td>'.$result['placar2p'].'</td>',
                'placar1s' => '<td>'.$result['placar1s'].'</td>',
                'placar2s' => '<td>'.$result['placar2s'].'</td>'
            ); // <--- adiciona
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<script>

$(function(){

    var html2 = '';

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

        html2 += '<div class="tab-pane" id="bloco-<?php echo $val['id'];?>" role="tabpanel"><td><?php echo $val['mandante'];?>x<?php echo $val['visitante'];?></td></div>';

    <?php } ?>

    $('#tabList').html(html2);

});

</script>




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Retorno Campeonatos:**

```
  {
"codigo": "17",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "6",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "19",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE OURO",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
  {
"codigo": "18",
"nome": "CIRCUITO ESCOLAR - SÉRIE PRATA",
"modalidade": "2",
"categoria": "4",
"sexo": "M",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"atualizacao": null,
"status": "N"
},
```

**Retorno Resultados**

```
{
"codigo": "30",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-08-31 00:00:00",
"horario": "19h",
"local": "4",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "7",
"visitante": "5",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "4",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "31",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-11 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "2",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "5",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "2",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "32",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-25 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "4",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "7",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "4",
"obs": null
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Em ambos os casos, você está varrendo o retorno e, quando a condição é satisfeita, você está criando um array sempre e substituindo na variável de retorno.

Você executar o **array_push($lista, itens...);** a cada iteração no retorno.

Obs: Cuidado com a URL de consumo da API, está com usuário e token, qualquer um com más intenções pode consumir os serviços.

Comment: Desculpe, é a primeira vez que consumo um Web Service, estou meio perdido, hahah, eu preciso executar um array_push? poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp